# home ubuntu server seems flaky since Jammy upgrade

Tags: upgrade

My home Ubuntu server seems to be a little flaky ever since running the 'jammy' upgrade of Ubuntu. I just tried an apt update and upgrade and it seems to not complete. I never saw this response before. Any feedback is appreciated.
Here is my terminal output:

```
61 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
ron@server:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  bluedevil breeze breeze-cursor-theme drkonqi gjs gnome-remote-desktop
  kde-config-sddm kde-config-updates kde-style-breeze kde-style-oxygen-qt5
  kinfocenter kscreen ksystemstats kwin-common kwin-data kwin-style-breeze
  kwin-x11 layer-shell-qt libapache2-mod-php7.4 libapache2-mod-php8.1
  libcolorcorrect5 libgjs0g libkf5sysguard-data libkfontinst5 libkfontinstui5
  libksgrd9 libksysguardformatter1 libksysguardsensorfaces1
  libksysguardsensors1 libksysguardsystemstats1 libkwaylandserver5
  libkwineffects13 libkwinglutils13 libkwinxrenderutils13 libkworkspace5-5
  liblayershellqtinterface5 libnotificationmanager1 liboxygenstyle5-5
  liboxygenstyleconfig5-5 libplasma-geolocation-interface5 libprocesscore9
  libprocessui9 libtaskmanager6 libweather-ion7 milou oxygen-sounds php8.1-cli
  php8.1-common php8.1-mysql php8.1-opcache php8.1-readline plasma-desktop
  plasma-desktop-data plasma-discover plasma-discover-backend-fwupd
  plasma-discover-backend-snap plasma-discover-common plasma-pa
  plasma-workspace qml-module-org-kde-ksysguard systemsettings
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.
```

As requested:

```
ron@server:~$ apt-cache policy bluedevil
bluedevil:
  Installed: 4:5.24.4-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 4:5.24.6-0ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
     4:5.24.6-0ubuntu0.1 500 (phased 20%)
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 4:5.24.4-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: I ran the first tow recommendations that were less risky. 1st one did nothing. 2nd one - sudo apt-get install <list of packages kept back> - isntalled 10 of the 61 held back so now only 51 are outstanding. I do not feel comfortable doing the aggressive solution.

Comment: For the package you chose `(phased 20%)`, so the culprit of that particular package is indeed Phased Updates -- do nothing about them, they will resolve themselves in a few days without any action by you.  Try a few others; you might find a different cause for them.

Comment: This morning I ran sudo apt-get install <packagename(s)> and more packages loaded. I then did it again with what was left and it loaded more. After running this about 4 times all packages loaded. Everything seems as it should now but I am still at a loss as to why.

Comment: You have not provided policy output on any of those packages so you are guessing...and asking us to guess. We have policy output on a single package, so we know that it was phasing. When it installed, then phasing completed for you. It's that simple, and just as promised.